# jQuery - Access a td inside a specific tr and table

Tags: jquery

I want to access td.EditButton inside tr.Act_Buttons inside the table TblGrid_grid_servico_2. I tried this with no success: `"#TblGrid_grid_servico_2 > tbody > tr.Act_Buttons > td.EditButton"`

Here is my code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="EditTable" id="TblGrid_grid_servico_2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <hr class="ui-widget-content" style="margin:1px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Act_Buttons">
            <td class="navButton">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="pData" class="fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-state-disabled">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-w"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nData" class="fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="EditButton">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sData" class="fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left">Enviar
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cData" class="fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left">Cancelar
                   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You might want to consider switch the tr ID to a class if you got more of these. If you switch it to a class your original code will work. If not then see answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IDs must be unique, try:

```
#Act_Buttons > td.EditButton
```

Your combination of selectors might work except for the `tr.Act_Buttons`. There you're targeting an element with the *class* of `Act_Buttons` when it's the ID. `.` matches classes, `#` matches IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Act_Buttons is an ID, not a class, so it should be:

```
#TblGrid_grid_servico_2 > tbody > tr#Act_Buttons > td.EditButton
```

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, everything before `#Act_Buttons > td.EditButton` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#` instead of `.` to target `tr id="Act_Buttons"` here:

```
$('#TblGrid_grid_servico_2 > tbody > tr#Act_Buttons > td.EditButton')
// ----------------------------------  ^ here ------------
```

Answer (score 0):

var td= $('#TblGrid_grid_servico_2 tbody').find('tr#Act_Buttons').find('td#EditButton');

// play further with the td and it's content..